# How to use a JMeter variable in JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, selenium, csv, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

I want to automate several users login with different credentials on the web page. I wrote code in JMeter with Selenium. I want to read usernames and passwords from an CSV file. For that I want to pass a JMeter variable in my code because I need it to be dynamic.

for example:

```
findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(${username}) <- here I want to pass JMeter variable

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()

WDS.browser.get('https://www.google.com/')

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.name("q")).
sendKeys(**${here I want to put JMeter variable}**)

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Could you please advise me on the best approach here?

Answer (score 2):

There is `WDS.vars` shorthand which maps to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance so you can use it for getting [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) values

```
findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys(WDS.vars.get("username")) <- here I want to pass JMeter variable

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()

WDS.browser.get('https://www.google.com/')

WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.name("q")).
sendKeys(WDS.vars.get("your_jmeter_variable_name"))

WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

More information:

- [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/)
- [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered/)